# Is there a way to reduce IPv6 address data to store?

Tags: ipv6

I need to store `IPv6` addresses of users connected through the Internet. Is there a way to cut part of the address without loss of uniqueness?

Comment: IPv6 addresses aren't as unique as you think. There are corporate firewalls that act as (NAT) even for IPv6 traffic. That is, all users that work at the same company have the same external IPv6 address.  **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: The 128-bit binary representation is already the most compact representation of an IPv6 address. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to use as little bits as possible. Maybe there are reserved or unused ranges.

Comment: Even if there was a way to shave off bits from a user's address and still be unique, the bottom line is that the IP address is not a good way to be generating unique IDs.   Even with IPv6, a user's address can easily change and it can be shared with other users.  There's a better way to accomplish your real goal, but we need you to elaborate on that is for us to help you.  So let me ask, why do you need to store a user's address?

Comment: Storage is cheap. There is no good reason to do this. Even on embedded systems, you'll pay a serious penalty in CPU if you try to compact the address any further somehow.

Comment: I need to increase computing efficiency and reduce memory footprint, but it does not really matter. Count of IPv6 addresses is 79228162514264337593543950336 times more than IPv4. I think that there can be a way to reduce amount of required bits to distinct one connection from another.

Comment: You are reluctant to elaborate on **what you are really trying to do**. So I can't help beyond advising you on the issues of using IP addresses as unique identifiers.  As Michael said, if your goal is to increase computing efficiency, any sort of hash algorithm to reduce the 128-bit address into something smaller is just going to be a bigger perf hit. 

A hash will also have a non-zero probability of collisions (duplicates). If you can live with duplicates, then your best bet is to use the simplest hash of all: simply `XOR` the leading 64-bits with the trailing 64-bits of the address.

Comment: Certainly I am not good at asking questions. The question is about IPv6 insights rather than my problems. Anyway thank you for your thoughts.